# How do I call a batch file from shared drive in a service created from batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-services

I have batch file which sets some parameters as follows-

```
SET APP_ROOT=D:\app_folder
SET APP_DATA=\\server1\folder1\folder2
Call %APP_DATA%\app_profilevariables.bat

C:\java\jdk1.7.0\bin\java.exe -jar "MyJar.jar"
```

When I run this batch file(double click) it is recognizing **APP_DATA** but after setting up a **service to run the batch file**, it does not recognize the path. It gives me error `The system could not recognize the path specified`. While all other commands are working properly including **APP_ROOT** and **C:\java\jdk1.7.0\bin\java.exe -jar "MyJar.jar"**.

Can anyone help to call a batch file from shared drive(server1)?

Comment: If running from a service then its a service account that attempts to use that network share, it needs to logon with credentials to do so.

Comment: Yeah! Got it. Thanks